# How To Get Reddit OAuth Array User Information?

Tags: php, oauth, reddit

That's probably an easy question. I'm using a modification of [Pathogen-David](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-PHP-Example) authentication code. I try to `echo` user account name without success. Any help would be super nice.

I tried this

```
$name = $response->name;// Does not work, returns blank
$name = $response["name"];// Does not work, returns blank
```

Code

```
[...rest of code]
else{
$params = array("code" => $_GET["code"], "redirect_uri" => $redirecturi);
$response = $client->getAccessToken($accessTokenUrl, "authorization_code", $params);
$accessTokenResult = $response["result"];
$client->setAccessToken($accessTokenResult["access_token"]);
$client->setAccessTokenType(OAuth2\Client::ACCESS_TOKEN_BEARER);
$response = $client->fetch("https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me");
$name = $response->name;//does not work return blank
$name = $response["name"];//does not work return blank

echo $name;
}
```

Comment: Can you try the following? `var_dump($response);` and post that output here?

Comment: @MatthijsOtterloo: The dump file is way too long. It looks like the array is split in several arrays.